# Iterating over a parameter distribution

Tags: python, for-loop, statistics

I have such script:

```
def simulacion(b=3.00, theta=1.00, delta=1.00, m=1000000):
    S= np.zeros(m)
    N = (np.floor(((np.random.pareto(b, m) + 1) * 1)- theta))
    i_N = [ x for x in N if x>=1]
    print(i_N)
    Y= np.zeros(0) 
    for i in i_N:
           Yi =(np.random.pareto(2+ 1/N[i],N[i])+1)*x_m
           S[i] = sum(Y_i)
           np.append(Y,Y_i)

    ES, VS, MS, VaRS = np.mean(S), np.var(S), np.percentile(S,50), np.percentile(S,5)
    return [S, ES, VS, MS, VaRS, N, Y]
```

Which is a simulation about an assurance policy with a Pareto distribution but as you may note, on the **for loop** i iterate over the parameter of the Pareto Distribution:

```
    Yi =(np.random.pareto(2+ 1/N[i],N[i])+1)*x_m
```

But i get this error code:

```
    Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices.
```

Which clear tells me that Python doesn't recognize the **For Loop** on the moment i generate the Pareto Simulations.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please carefully check what you're doing.

You are iterating over a random *sample* of floats.  You cannot iterate over a continuous *distribution*, which is a probability "cloud".

I don't see how you conclude that Python doesn't recognize a `for` loop, since the error is thrown from *within* that loop.

You *did* correctly print the array of offending values: `i_N`.  That is an array of floats.  I float cannot be used as a subscript.  I suspect that what you want on that line is

```
`N[int(i)]`
```

Will that solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, sorry i notice that when i was posting this, even i answer my own question, anyway thanks

Comment: Great!  I suggest that you clean up your posting now, so it can be more useful to future site visitors.  That is, after all, the purpose of this site.

Answer (score 0):

I get the error, it's because the data type i was iterating in:

```
 N = (np.floor(((np.random.pareto(b, m) + 1) * 1)- theta))
```

Was an array of floats, so i just simply convert it to an array of ints with:

```
  N = N.astype(int)
```